# How to grant access cross site script

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I am trying to get values from parent document through an iframe and obviously I am getting permission denied error. I was wondering if there is any workaround for that, like create exception or anything like that?

Can we add headers that allow cross site communication or anything that grant access?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using XMLHTTPRequest (ajax) or `postMessage`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If you run the remote site you can enable [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/) or you can write a proxy script to make the request and return the data.